# User id from app engine User API is different from the user_id in the credential

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I used app engine User API to get the user id of the current user, but when I double check on using the given access token for the same user on the googleapis it gave me different user id for the same gmail address. Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Thanks.